# Dynamic Contour generation and project on google maps

Tags: google-maps-api, contour, asp.net

Is it possible to generate contour map layer at runtime and overlap or project on google maps.

I am using google map api v3 and want to generate contour map layer using data from sql server and project on google map.

Comment: is this contour data more detailed than the terrain layer in google maps? like http://maps.google.com/?ll=36.710334,-118.412189&spn=0.021502,0.045447&t=p&z=15

Comment: Yes @Mapperz . We have only data for specific area that is coordinate and the height value for the the coordinate coming from database

Comment: Would generate the contours to KML or GeoJSON and add as a layer. GlobalMapper can create the contours from points with height elevation - http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/global-mapper/

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz Instead of using third party tool is there any java-script or C# code that can convert the x,y,height to shp file.

Comment: @Mapperz even something like heat map that plot the values in different color layers might work, i guess.